# PHP gd make thumbnail from generated image

Tags: php, png, thumbnails, gd

I have a php script `cakeChart.php` which is generating simple cake.

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

$white    = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$gray     = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0);
$navy     = imagecolorallocate($image, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80);
$red      = imagecolorallocate($image, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);

imagefilledarc($image, 50, 50, 100, 50, 0, 45, $navy, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image, 50, 50, 100, 50, 45, 75 , $gray, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image, 50, 50, 100, 50, 75, 360 , $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);


header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

In file `createThumb.php` I want to load generated image from `cakeChart.php`.
Something like(I know it is bad):

```
$pngImage = imagecreatefrompng("pieChart.php");
```

I want to make thumbnail of this image. Right now the only reference on this php file is this

```
<a href="pieChart.php" target="blank">PHP pie chart</a><br>
```

but I want to replace this text with tumb, whitch will be generated in `createThumb.php`. Is it possible to make image with `cakeChart.php` and then convert it to thumbnail with`createThumb.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need another script that called `cakeChart.php` and resized it, like so:

```
<?php
$src = imagecreatefrompng('http://example.com/cakeChart.php');

$width = imagesx($src);
$height = imagesy($src);
// resize to 50% of original:
$new_width = $width * .5;
$new_height = $height * .5;

$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Then your HTML would reference that file as an image source:

```
<a href="pieChart.php" target="blank">
    <img src="http://example.com/cakeChartThumb.php" alt="PHP pie chart">
</a>
```

While this will work, it is not an efficient use of server resources. Even a small number of page views might cause the server CPU usage to spike and impact performance.  You should really create both files once and save them to disk, referencing them in your HTML as you would any other image file.